# How to extract non-common records between two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames like these:

```
set.seed(123)
a<-data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
      y=sample(1:3, 9, T))   

b<-data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:4], each=4),
      y=sample(1:3, 16, T))
```

How to extract the non-common records between them with an outcome like this:

```
a 1
b 2
c 2
d 2
d 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way:

```
x <- rbind(unique(a), unique(b))
x[! (duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)),]

   x y
1  a 1
7  c 2
5  b 2
9  c 1
13 d 3
14 d 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One (bit long maybe) way

```
sort(union(paste(b$x, b$y), paste(a$x, a$y))[!union(paste(b$x, b$y), paste(a$x, a$y)) %in% intersect(paste(b$x, b$y), paste(a$x, a$y))]) 

## [1] "a 1" "b 2" "c 1" "c 2" "d 2" "d 3"
```

Or

```
sort(c(setdiff(paste(a$x, a$y), paste(b$x, b$y)), setdiff(paste(b$x, b$y), paste(a$x, a$y))))
```

Comment: Thanks you, David and Matthew! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
x1 <- rbind(unique(a), unique(b))
res <- as.data.frame(table(x1))
 res[res$Freq==1,-3] #order is different
 #   x y
#1  a 1
#3  c 1
#6  b 2
#7  c 2
#8  d 2
#12 d 3
```